# XPath - Return ALL nodes with certain string pattern

Tags: python, xpath, python-3.x

Here is a sample from the doc I am working with:

```
<idx:index xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.belscript.org/schema/index index.xsd" idx:belframework_version="2.0">
   <idx:namespaces>
      <idx:namespace idx:resourceLocation="http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/entrez-gene-ids-hmr.belns"/>
      <idx:namespace idx:resourceLocation="http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/hgnc-approved-symbols.belns"/>
      <idx:namespace idx:resourceLocation="http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/mgi-approved-symbols.belns"/>
```

I can get all nodes with name "namespace" with the following code:

```
tree = etree.parse(self.old_files)
urls = tree.xpath('//*[local-name()="namespace"]')
```

This would return a list of the 3 `namespace` elements. But what if I want to get to the data in the `idx:resourceLocation` attribute? Here is my attempt at doing that, using the [XPath docs](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) as a guide.

```
urls = tree.xpath('//*[local-name()="namespace"]/@idx:resourceLocation="http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/"',
                          namespaces={'idx' : 'http://www.belscript.org/schema/index'})
```

What I want is all nodes that have an attribute starting with `http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace`. So in the sample doc, it would return me only those strings in the `resourceLocation` attribute. Unfortunately, the syntax is not quite right, and I am having trouble deriving the proper syntax from the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
//*[local-name()="namespace"]/@idx:resourceLocation
```

or

```
//idx:namespace/@idx:resourceLocation
```

or, if you want only those `@idx:resourceLocation` attributes that start with `"http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace"` you could use

```
'''//idx:namespace[
       starts-with(@idx:resourceLocation,
       "http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace")]
           /@idx:resourceLocation'''
```

---

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content = '''\
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.xxx.com/zzz/yyy" xmlns:idx="http://www.belscript.org/schema/index">
<idx:index xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.belscript.org/schema/index index.xsd" idx:belframework_version="2.0">
   <idx:namespaces>
      <idx:namespace idx:resourceLocation="http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/entrez-gene-ids-hmr.belns"/>
      <idx:namespace idx:resourceLocation="http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/hgnc-approved-symbols.belns"/>
      <idx:namespace idx:resourceLocation="http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/mgi-approved-symbols.belns"/>
      </idx:namespaces>
      </idx:index>
      </root>
      '''

root = ET.XML(content)
namespaces = {'xsi': 'http://www.xxx.com/zzz/yyy',
              'idx': 'http://www.belscript.org/schema/index'}
for item in root.xpath(
    '//*[local-name()="namespace"]/@idx:resourceLocation', namespaces=namespaces):
    print(item)
```

yields

```
http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/entrez-gene-ids-hmr.belns
http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/hgnc-approved-symbols.belns
http://resource.belframework.org/belframework/1.0/namespace/mgi-approved-symbols.belns
```